# TSQL - Any of Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following query is extremely expensive to run on my `150kk` records table:

```
SELECT MAX(myId) 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY C1,C2,C3 
HAVING count(1) > 1
```

The estimate execution plan points that Sorting will represent 72% of the operation. This i believe is because of the the `MAX`.

The thing is: i don't really need the `MAX`... i need `ANY`... this is supposed to be deleting duplicated records, so deleting the one that came in first or later is fine with me...

Is there a way to "cut out" that sorting?!?

**Edit 1:**
I would like to first retrieve records being deleted (via Id) to double check if group by 2 columns is enough

Comment: I honestly believe that sorting is related to aggregation but... you may well try `select 1 from Table1 ...` and see what happens.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek hummmm sort still there! thats a very nice catch...

Comment: 72% of what? Please share your execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I ended up creating a temporary table, selecting all the ids to it.
Then, upon realizing that duplication was around 20%, I disabled all other indexes on the main table, deleted the duplicated rows and rebuilt the indexes...
Whole operation just completed: 3h total... not so bad...

Answer (score 6):

For this query:

```
SELECT MAX(myId) 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY C1, C2, C3 
HAVING count(1) > 1;
```

Try an index on `Table1(C1, C2, C3, myId)`.

To delete records, I would recommend:

```
with todelete as (
      select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by c1, c2, c3 order by myid desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     )
delete todelete 
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

the same query can be expressed without aggregation in this way:

```
 SELECT t1.myId 
 FROM Table1 t1
 where exists
    (select 1 from table1 t2 t1.c1=t2.c1 and t1.c2=t2.c2 and t1.c3=t2.c3 and t1.myid<t2.myid)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should work a bit faster since we are not aggregating

```
;WITH CTE AS(
         SELECT myId,
         ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1) AS RowN
   FROM dbo.Table1
)
DELETE FROM CTE 
WHERE RowN > 1
```